# Laravel 5.5 - chained Jobs not processed in sequence

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5.5

I am fairly new to Laravel and the whole Queue/Worker/Job architecture.

My goal in the end is to have a server running with Laravel which creates JPEG Images from PSD Files from a specific Dropbox Account. 
(The PSDs can be up to 500MB in file size)

My problem right now is: The chained jobs are not processed in sequence. Currently I am on my local dev machine with a database queue driver. (Do I need another Driver? e.g. Redis?)

I start the queue with the artisan command "artisan queue:work".
The queue then start to process **all** Download Jobs, then **all** Convert Jobs and then **all** the Delete Jobs.

**What I need it to do is follow the chain of jobs!**

1. Download one resource.
2. Convert it to different formats.
3. Delete the temporary downloaded resource.

My code inside the command which queries the Dropbox API:

```
// After Dropbox API Call, process the response array
ProcessDropboxMetadata::dispatch($metadata);
```

My code inside the ProcessDropboxMetadata->handle method

```
// Inside ProcessDropboxMetadata Job, create the job Sequence:
// Download, Convert, Delete
DownloadDropboxResource::withChain([
    new ConvertDropboxResource($dbxResource, 'thumb'),
    new ConvertDropboxResource($dbxResource, 'small'),
    new ConvertDropboxResource($dbxResource, 'medium'),
    new ConvertDropboxResource($dbxResource, 'large'),
    new ConvertDropboxResource($dbxResource, 'huge'),
    new DeleteTempDropboxResource($dbxResource)
])->dispatch($dbxResource);
```

In Laravel 5.4 there was a "--sync" flag. In 5.5 it got removed?

My current setup:
Laravel Framework 5.5.12
PHP 7.1.10
Windows 10 x64

Comment: chain only guarantee you all these tasks of one job are do in sequence, but it still do tasks one by one, if you push all download job to queue, it will download one by one, meanwhile push another job of convert into queue one by one, once download job all done, it start works on convert one by one and push delete into queue. queue is first in first out, so it ends the way you see

Comment: Ah okay. I just tried 

`// Download and Convert Jobs erstellen
            DownloadDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource);
            ConvertDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource, 'thumb');
            ConvertDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource, 'small');
            ConvertDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource, 'medium');
            ConvertDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource, 'large');
            ConvertDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource, 'huge');
            DeleteTempDropboxResource::dispatch($dbxResource);`

and it seems to work. :)

Comment: You could end up with a race condition depending on job queue you are dispatching to and the number of workers...

which processes queues in the order they are listed in your configuration.